# Is there a good way to cancel/rollback an async realm transaction mid way through its logic?

Tags: java, android, realm

I have been going over the realm documentation and found no feasible way of cancelling an asynchronous transaction from within the transaction "body" i.e. [Realm.Transaction.execute()](https://realm.io/docs/java/5.4.1/api/io/realm/Realm.Transaction.html#execute-io.realm.Realm-)

So the only recourse I seem to have if I want to use the [executeTransactionAsync()](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#asynchronous-transactions) API's is to do something like:

```
realm.executeTransactionAsync(
    new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(@NonNull Realm realm) {
            // pretend we have some inter dependent database operations here
            if (failureCondition) {
                throw new Error("Failed transaction");
            }

            // and more here... 
        }
    }, 
    new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Throwable error) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, error.getMessage());
        }
    }
);
```

Is there really no better way to do this? If re-ordering the operations such that a simple return would suffice and the transaction could be partially committed was an option that is obviously what I would do but what if it isn't.

Of course the above is  technically functionally identical to just calling `realm.cancelTransaction()` in execute(), since it causes the attempt to commit the transaction that no-longer exists to throw an exception anyways. However, judging from the fact that the actual async transaction code behind this nice API doesn't check with `realm.isInTransaction()` before attempting to commit nor allows execute() to throw any checked exceptions neither approach seems to be something the designers even considered a valid use case.

I guess in the end I sort of answered myself, so perhaps the better question would be... is this a problem with the design of the API itself or am I just attempting to do something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: The only way to cancel the async transaction is by throwing an unchecked exception, yes. Anything that is `RuntimeException` would suffice, I think.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce that is unfortunate, I had hoped I would have missed something to be honest.